# How can I buy Hjerim Manor in Windhelm when I've sided with the Imperials?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok so, I have a problem where I want to buy the manor in Windhelm. I have done the mission 'Blood on the Ice' to start to be able to get it but to fully be able to purchase it I also have to do the civil war mission for the Stormcloaks (Rescue from Fort Neugrad). The problem is that I'm the Thane of Whiterun and have sided with the Imperials so it won't let me do the mission... is there any way I can buy the manor?

Answer (score 6):

Completing the Civil War questline for the Imperials will cause a new Jarl, Brunwulf Free-Winter, to be appointed in Windhelm. Once this happens, you will be able to purchase Hjerim from him.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Windhelm guards are replaced by Imperials, start the quest Bloodon the Ice by lockpicking inside the house Hjerim. This will start the quest. Then investigate the items and make sure you pick up 2 journals, a flyer, and an amulet. Sell the amulet to Callixto, talk to Viola, then talk to Jorlief to finish the quest. You can actually go straight in the court wizard and tell him about the crime and he said he didn't and tells you to wait in the Stone Quarter at midnight. Then kill the murderer, then talk to Jorlief, which should complete the quest. Don't forget to help assist people of Windhelm and then buy the house.